# rewrite rule not redirecting http to https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, url-rewriting

Currently we are trying to setup a redirect from htttp to https in our web.config limited to the domains we use. But it's not working.

```
<rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:[^\\.]+\.)?mysite\.com(\/.*)?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

This rule works fine in a regex editor. But not on the webserver. http://rubular.com/r/3NQTozcigZ

```
^(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)?(?:[^\\.]+\.)?mysite\.com(\/.*)?$
```

Looking at the failedreqlogfiles pattern_match is false. Any insights?

After doing some more testing I'm finding that this works.

```
http://sub.site.com/
```

But this will not work.

```
http://sub.site.com/Account/Logon
```

Comment: Seems ok, have tried to edit the rule from the IIS url rewrite module? Is it ok?

Comment: I think it's something particular to mod rewrite. (.*) works fine. but other regex won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern used in `url` is here only to be matched again the requested path (and only the path, not the url).

If you want to check the domain as well as if https is used or not, you have to rely on the conditions:

```
<rule name="Redirect mysite.com to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="mysite\.com$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

This rule will check that both conditions are true (that is what `logicalGrouping="MatchAll"` is here for) on any path (`.*`):

- The request was not using HTTPS
- The domain requested ends with `mysite.com`

For reference: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#Accessing_URL_Parts_from_a_Rewrite_Rule

Comment: It should because the pattern used to check the `{HTTP_HOST}` just validate that it finishes by `mysite.com`. So for example `www.mysite.com` and `blog.mysite.com` would be valid.

Comment: When I write finishes I mean ends with if it is easier to understand!

Answer (score 1):

Do you need the regex? If you're just redirecting all traffic to HTTPS, something like this should work:

```
<rule name="HTTP to HTTPS redirect" stopProcessing="true">
   <conditions>
      <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
   </conditions>

   <action 
      type="Redirect" 
      redirectType="Permanent" 
      url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" 
      appendQueryString="false" 
   />
</rule>
```

I'd be inclined to use `redirectType="Permanent"` instead of `"Found"`, since an `HTTP 301` response is generally better for SEO.

If you're permanently moving your site to HTTPS, you might also want to look at sending [the `Strict-Transport-Security` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security). This will ensure that modern browsers never request your site over a non-secure connection.